# What is "into" function for?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have a function that is defined like this:

```
(defn delete-rule [rules rule]
  (om/transact! rules
    (fn [rules] (into [] (remove #(= rule %) rules)))))
```

What is the purpose of `into` here? 
Wouldn't that produce exactly the same result as the one on the above:

```
(defn delete-rule [rules rule]
  (om/transact! rules
    (fn [rules] (remove #(= rule %) rules))))
```

Comment: into transforms the result into a vector, needed in this situation because `om` doesn't support lists as cursors (when you update or transact a cursor the resulting value must be a hash-map or a vector)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation for [remove](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/remove):

> Returns a lazy sequence of the items in coll for which (pred item)
> returns false. pred must be free of side-effects. Returns a transducer
> when no collection is provided.

From the documentation for [into](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into):

> Returns a new coll consisting of to-coll with all of the items of
> from-coll conjoined. A transducer may be supplied.

So the difference is, the delete-rule version with `into` returns a non-lazy vector, whereas the version without `into` returns a lazy sequence.

The particulars with your function is that `om` doesn't support lists (or lazy sequences) as cursors, only maps and vectors, that's why the output of remove must be converted to vector.

Hope that helps.

Comment: [vec](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vec) could be used here instead of `ino []`.

Comment: Or better still, since transducers exist now: `(into [] (remove #(= rule %)) rules)`. You still get a vector out, and you avoid the overhead of creating many lazy sequence cels.